# Capistrano stops at git:check

Tags: git, capistrano

When I run a `cap <stage> deploy --trace` I got:

```
> $ bundle exec cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rbenv:validate (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:validate
** Invoke rbenv:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:map_bins
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_shared_assets (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_shared_assets
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
 INFO [d204de77] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/control-panel/ on 10.0.1.6
 INFO [d204de77] Finished in 0.274 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO Uploading /tmp/prey-control-panel/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [a9e748c9] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/control-panel/git-ssh.sh on 10.0.1.6
 INFO [a9e748c9] Finished in 0.274 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
```

And it stops right there. I think the problem is related with the others public keys I've. I work as a DevOps and I've about 5 different keys that I use frequently.

Any ideas? Should I delete all my keys or something? :)

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the source for the git:check capistrano task. Can you post all or part of that code?

Comment: @GregBurghardt this is the git:check task http://pastebin.com/3tCpk7jb

Comment: Can you run `git ls-remote repo_url` from your command line? If that command is being run on the production servers, can you log in to the server and run that command?

Comment: I'm able to run git ls-remote on both local and remote machine. Anyway, I found a workaround to this problem by switching orders of the IdentityFiles on top of my ~/.ssh/config file. I don't really know why this solved the issue, but now I can deploy. Thanks for your help @GregBurghardt

Comment: @borisquiroz did you ever figure out why this worked?

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem removing and adding again my ssh keys. Looks like I had too many keys on my ssh-agent...

```
ssh-add -D ; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be that I needed to add the SSH key from my server to Bitbucket. Weirdly, it had been working for a bit without having to do that.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not have git installed on the server.  I found this by setting the log level to debug in deploy.rb.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your Gemlock was updated but not pushed. Try updating capistrano gem and push to git repo, then try deploying again.